# API to share a folder on Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm looking for a way to share a folder with other Dropbox account through API or similar. My code creates a new directory which I want to auto-share with other person, but currently the only way I've found is to create the folder and share it from the UI. I'm looking for a way to automate this process.

Thanks!

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202884395-Collaborate-folder-throw-API ]

Answer (score 0):

No Dropbox APi is not offering this function yet, but we can expect this in the future

[refer this blog post](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/07/new-in-beta-shared-folder-metadata/)